# How to allow SHA1 hash function in chrony?

Tags: hash, synchronization, sha1, ntp, key-generator

I use chrony to the synchronization between two devices. When I try to create a key with the SHA1 function, the next error appears:

```
chronyc>keygen 73 SHA1 256 
Unknown hash function SHA1
```

How could I set up the SHA1 hash function?

Comment: Do you have the `openssl` stuff installed? What OS is this? What version of Crrony?

Comment: Yes, I have openssl intalled. The OS is linux is and the chrony version is the last one in development.

Answer (score -1):

i ran the command " keygen 73 sha1 256" 
and got the same error message, the fix is to type SHA1 capital letters, and that made it working. hope this help someone.